# AngularJS: Multiple file upload window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-file-upload

I need a separate upload window to show queue/progress as shown in the image below.
I am using [this](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) module to upload multiple files. Find the following image for desired output.[image: Required output]

Comment: Please don't use both tags angular and angularjs ... angular tag is used for the new implementation of the framework after version 2 and angularjs for the first version of the framework. According to the module that you put link to I guess you are using **angularjs** - you can edit it by yourself :)

Comment: @codtex Can you help me with the solution

Comment: If you provide code that you were trying to achieve what you want, I can try to help you, but not build a solution from scratch for you :)